# Need help to understand Angular 2/Typescript modules declaration in Prime NG

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm playing with Angular 2 using Typescript and I'm using prime ng (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) for ui components.
What I don't understand is that prime ng declares its modules in this way:

```
export declare class TooltipModule {
}
```

So, I have two questions about this approach:

1. Why it does not use the @NgModule decorator? (like I do for all my own modules)
2. What is the purpose of "declare" keyword (I read a couple of answer regarding this, but it's still unclear to me :P)

UPDATE:

Even Angular2 itself declares modules in that way, for example:

```
export declare class HttpModule {
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I think that @NgModule is a totally different thing compared to the angular.module in angular 1.x and that it's just a way to configure the application (the "main" file), the other "things" are just classes... am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a [Typescript Definition file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) (different from the source code). It's mainly used for compile-time type safety and tooling (i.e. intellisense).

But generally let's say a library isn't written in Typescript. We could write a Typescript definition file and we could use that like as a facade of the vanilla JS library. Here we would getting *typing*, which you don't get with plain JS.

Say we have the following distribution bundle:

```
// this is the build distribution
tooptip
  |
  +-- src
  |    +-- index.ts
  |    +-- tooltip.ts  // actual source code
  |
  +-- index.js
  +-- tooltip.js
  +-- tooltip.d.ts     // definition file
```

Here if you were to say

```
import { ToolTipModule } from 'primeng/tooltip';
```

If the definition file wasn't there, this wouldn't work, as the Typescript file is in the `src`.

So here we just use the definition file which gives us all the typing. The `.js` file is the already compiled Typescript source code that has the actual implementation.

And because `'primeng/tooltip'` points to `index.js` and `index.js` points to `tooltip.js`, `tooltip.js` would be loaded at runtime, not the definition file.

If you look at the `.ts` (the source) file and not the `.d.ts` (the definition) file you should see what you are familiar with, with the `@NgModule`